# shift file names with a batch file

Tags: batch-file, batch-rename

Here is the file name format.  The leading number is the layer and the second number is the material (3D printer).

```
01118_7.tif,
01118_6.tif,
01118_5.tif,
01118_4.tif,
01118_3.tif,
01118_2.tif,
01118_1.tif,
01118_0.tif
```

What I need to do is shift the files ending in _1, _4, _6 six places higher. So, 01124_1, 01124_4, 01124_6 while the rest of the files stay the same.  I need to do it all the way down to layer 00112_*.

I'd like to do this via a batch file if I can.  Was trying to follow a guide but the name format is tripping me up.
[Basic excel format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkGmY.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [2-minute tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). 
Moreover, open Help Center and read at least _What topics can I ask about here_? 
Then you know what we expect from questioners: showing us the code on 
where you stuck solving the task by yourself and explaining why you fail to complete the task. Sorry, but Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service

Comment: More asking for help on how to format the command.  I was looking at this site http://mintywhite.com/windows-7/7maintenance/mass-convert-file-names-windows-batch-file/ but the layer number before the material number is giving excel problems.  If I can get one file name example then I can populate the spreadsheet and make the .bat file from there.  Just wondering if there are wildcard commands that I don't know that could help with parsing the name of the file.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell if you need to modify file names that appear within a text file, or if you need to rename files. Either way, I have a simple solution using one of two hybrid JScript/batch regex utilities:

Modify filenames within a text file using [JREPL.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044):

```
jrepl "^\d{5}(?=_[146]\.tif)" "lpad(Number($0)+6,'00000')" /i /j /f test.txt /O -
```

Rename files within the current directory using [JREN.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6081):

```
jren "^\d{5}(?=_[146]\.tif$)" "lpad(Number($0)+6,'00000')" /i /j
```

Use `call jrepl` or `call jren` if you put the command within a batch script.

Answer (score 0):

It took me awhile to understand that "shift file names six places higher" really means "add six to file name".

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "numbers=/1/4/6/"
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=_." %%a in ('dir /B /A-D *.tif') do (
   if "!numbers:/%%b/=!" neq "%numbers%" (
      set "newNum=1%%a+6"
      ECHO ren "%%a_%%b.tif" "!newNum:~1!_%%b.tif"
   )
)
```

If the names are not in files, but are lines of text placed in a text file, change the `'dir /B /A-D *.tif'` command by the name of the text file.